# Accidently created a partion table (GParted)

Tags: linux, debian, partition, gparted

I've been tinkering with the Debian side of my dual boot XP/Linux system.

Whilst trying to mount a drive so I get get at the .deb wireless files on my external hard drive, (using Gparted) I managed to accidently create a partition table on my 250GB external HHD. Is there anyway I can get back the 200GB or so worth of data that it seems to have wiped?

XP cant even read the External HDD any more (it doesn't show up in my computer, but does in the device manager)

Gparted (linux), can see the dive, but it looks a bit empty, so I don't have high hopes.

Thanks for reading,

Jonathan

Comment: Isn't this more of a SuperUser.com question?

Answer (score 1):

Successfully recovered using TestDisk :) Hopefully this will help anyone in the future. <3

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: You should accept your own answer; this way others know you're not still looking for help

Answer (score 0):

Partition tables are just that, the data is still there.  If you knew the original location of the partition you could have placed it back where it belonged using fdisk or parted.  (One of the minor dangers of using a GUI vs command line).  Glad you were able to recover! ;-)